# Download Base64 image through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an image panel that displays the image titles and a link to download the image. I have an `onclick` function that gathers the base64 data from the database and then 'decodes' it. However, when I decode it I'm getting back a string of Chinese text..which is obviously not what I'm looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.downloadAttachment').on('click', function() {

            var documentId = $(this).attr("data-id");
            console.log(documentId)
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                //data: id,
                async: false,
                type: 'GET',
                //url: baseUrl + 'rest/incdDocument/getAll?branchCode=' + brCode + '&receivedDate=' + receiveDate + '&complaintID=' + cId + '&incidentID=' + incidentId+ '&documentID='+documentId,
                url: baseUrl + 'rest/incdDocument/get?branchCode=009&receivedDate=03/10/2017&complaintID=170&incidentID=3'+'&documentID='+documentId,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        var image = Base64.decode(data.data);
                        window.open(image, '_blank');              
                    }
                },
                error: function(request, status, error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            });

            return false;

        })
    });
```

Is there a better way to extract this data and actually turn it into an image?

Comment: look into data uri's, then you wont need to decode the base64 data at all

Comment: @JaromandaX, but it needs to have the prefix of data:whatever type is is. Correct?

Comment: yes, read the documentation (MDN is considered a good source)

Comment: @JaromandaX I have read the documentation. I am coming here because I am stuck and cannot figure this out.

Comment: so, you've tried something like `window.open(\`data:image/jpeg;base64,${data.data}\`, '_blank');` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX, Yes I have. however not all of them are going to be jpegs or images. Also when pasting the string into a website like this https://www.base64decode.org/ it says it is invalid. That was why I was trying to decode

Comment: "however not all of them are going to be jpegs or images" you might need to specify that in the question. And also give info of the server side code.

Comment: can the image type be determined on the server? also, if the base64 is invalid, then it's invalid, unless whatever `Base64.decode` can fix some type of error that is "minor" (lack of `=` padding for example) - in that case you'll need to Base64.decode then encode back to base64 I guess

Comment: If they aren't all images, then the server definitely needs to respond with an indication of what the data is before you can blindly open it in a new window

Comment: @JaromandaX I do not have access to any server code. I can only work in javascript or jquery and work with what I have. And I only have a snippit that tells me if it's 'pdf, doc, png, ect.'

Comment: `a snippit that tells me` what is this "snippit" - if you know the type, then you have `an indication of what the data is`

Comment: The snippit is just  'pdf, doc, png, ect.'

Answer (score -1):

Searching for like this ?
var image = new Image();
image.src = data; (complete base64 sting with imagetype)

Download Image

Make a download.php file with return the a image with 
header('Content-type:image/png'); or other image type

Comment: I am not using php. I am just using javascript and jquery. Hence the tags

Comment: New image() is javascript

Comment: Yes, but 'make a download.php file' is php

Comment: Correct. Is option 2.   Check also canvas te maken a image from base64 string.

Comment: But why would I want to make a canvas if I just want to download it? The user does not see this on the screen